# How to restrict non SSL connection in RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

### Server Version: `MySQL 5.7`

#### 1. Create a test user with `REQUIRE SSL` option

`CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL;`

#### 2. Give specific permission to this user

`GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO 'test'@'%';`

#### 3. Check SSL_TYPE

`SHOW CREATE USER test` it gives `ANY`

#### Problem,

I can connect to mysql server with SSL and also without SSL. Also when I connect without SSL, `STATUS;` query is also showing `Cipher in use ...` which means I'm using SSL. How to restrict Non-SSL connection or please let me know what I'm wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer. Setting  `require_secure_transport = ON` solved my problem. I'm not sure this is the preferred way to restrict insecure connection. please comment out if I'm wrong. Thank you.

### Update

- This parameter is not able to modify in RDS

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Parameter Group with `require_secure_transport = ON` and modify your database configuration to associate with your new Parameter Group.

[image: Parameter Group]

You can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithDBInstanceParamGroups.html) how to work with AWS DB Parameter Groups.